# Having trouble clicking an HTML element with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Here's the Xpath for the button I'd like to click:

`//*[@id="interstitial_join_btn"]`

but when I run something like:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="interstitial_join_btn"]')`

the console spits out:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="interstitial_join_btn"]"}
>     (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.163)

This is to click the join button for a meeting within the web-version of WebEx.

If I could brute force it with `pyautogui` like some other stuff in my script I would but I've been scratching my head at this for days now (newbie to selenium/HTML)

Thanks

Comment: Please provide url to reproduce your issue

Comment: @DipakBachhav Unfortunately the URL is only available if you have a WebEx account through my university

Comment: here is the HTML for the element: `<button role="button" title="Start meeting" id="interstitial_start_btn" class="style-rest-1IrDU style-theme-green-22KBC style-join-button-yqbh_ style-size-huge-3dFcq style-botton-outline-none-1M0ur" tabindex="0" aria-label="Start meeting">Start meeting</button>`

Answer (score 1):

are you sure that the page is completely loaded before you trying to access the element? Maybe you have to wait a bit.
e.g.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'interstitial_join_btn')))
```

see also [Selenium - wait until element is present, visible and interactable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable) 
and https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

BUT: if your HTML code you have provided is correct, you simply have a typo:
`interstitial_start_btn`
vs
`interstitial_join_btn`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I've simply been using time.sleep to wait for the element but I know that shouldn't be the problem as I am altering other parts of that page already. It might help if I show a part of the HTML tree for the button(ignore that it says interstitial start button, that is only when the class is not open): '<button role="button" title="Start meeting" id="interstitial_start_btn" class="style-rest-1IrDU style-theme-green-22KBC style-join-button-yqbh_ style-size-huge-3dFcq style-botton-outline-none-1M0ur" tabindex="0" aria-label="Start meeting">Start meeting</button>'

Comment: Sorry this is clearer: `<button role="button" title="Start meeting" id="interstitial_start_btn" class="style-rest-1IrDU style-theme-green-22KBC style-join-button-yqbh_ style-size-huge-3dFcq style-botton-outline-none-1M0ur" tabindex="0" aria-label="Start meeting">Start meeting</button>`

Comment: so you just trying to click the wrong button? see my updated answer `interstitial_start_btn` vs `interstitial_join_btn`

Comment: As I explained in my response to your comment the button is labelled interstitial_start_btn only when class is not in session. The id updates when the class is available to join so this is not the issue.